# Enzyme cannot read this.props.match.params from ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I just got into unit testing for my project, the adapter is setup correctly, and I wrote some tests. A few of my tests throw errors, namely the ones where I include a variable from the redux state. The following is just one of them:

```
export class BasePage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const baseId = this.props.match.params.baseId;
    const access_token = this.props.auth;
    if (this.props.match.params.baseId) {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchSingleBase(baseId, access_token));
    }
  }
}
```

The below named error occurred in the above `componentDidMount` as well, but I was able to mitigated that with the `if` statement.

The `BasePage` is rendered via Router in app.js:

```
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <main>
          ...
          <Route exact path="/single-base/:baseId" component={BasePage} />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
```

On the basepage, I return:

```
return (
    <div className="basepage">
        {title}
        <UserList baseId={this.props.match.params.baseId} />
        <MessageList baseId={this.props.match.params.baseId} />
    </div>
);
```

If statement here does not work.
When running npm test I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
```

And lastly, the very basics of the test:

```
import React from "react";
import ConnectedBasePage, { BasePage } from "./basepage";
import { shallow, mount, render } from "enzyme";

describe("<BasePage/>", () => {
    it("Renders without crashing", () => {
        shallow(<BasePage/>);
    });
});
```

How to solve this error ?

Comment: You try to shallow render `<BasePage/>` in your test but don't pass any parameters to it.
`this.props` is an empty object `this.props.match` is undefined so you're indeed trying to get property of undefined as described in error you've got.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass mock match object:

```
const match = {
                params : { 
                            baseId : 1 //any id you want to set
                         }
               }

describe("<BasePage/>", () => {
it("Renders without crashing", () => {
    shallow(<BasePage match={match}/>);
 });
});
```